# generating large number of random variates

Tags: python, performance, numpy, random

I'm trying to figure out the best way to generate many random numbers in python.  The difficult part is that I won't know how many numbers I'll need before runtime

I have a program that uses random numbers one at a time, but it needs to do this many times.

The things I've tried so far are:

- generate random numbers one at a time using `random.random()`
- generate random numbers one at a time using `np.random.rand()`
- generate random numbers in a batch of N using `np.random.rand(N)`
- generate random numbers in a batch of N using `np.random.rand(N)` and make a new batch after the first N have all been used (I've tried two different implementations, and both are slower than just generating one number at a time)

In the following script, I compare the first three of these methods (for both uniform and normally-distributed random numbers).

I don't know whether the `p` function is really necessary, but I wanted to do equivalent things with the random numbers in each case, and this seemed like the simplest way to do that.

```
#!/bin/python3

import time
import random
import numpy as np

def p(x):
    pass

def gRand(n):
    for i in range(n):
        p(random.gauss(0,1))

def gRandnp1(n):
    for i in range(n):
        p(np.random.randn())

def gRandnpN(n):
    rr=np.random.randn(n)
    for i in rr:
        p(i)

def uRand(n):
    for i in range(n):
        p(random.random())

def uRandnp1(n):
    for i in range(n):
        p(np.random.rand())

def uRandnpN(n):
    rr=np.random.rand(n)
    for i in rr:
        p(i)

tStart=[]
tEnd=[]
N=1000000
for f in [uRand, uRandnp1, uRandnpN]:
    tStart.append(time.time())
    f(N)
    tEnd.append(time.time())

for f in [gRand, gRandnp1, gRandnpN]:
    tStart.append(time.time())
    f(N)
    tEnd.append(time.time())

print(np.array(tEnd)-np.array(tStart))
```

A representative example of the output of this timing script is:
`[ 0.26499939  0.45400381  0.19900227  1.57501364  0.49000382  0.23000193]`
The first three numbers are for uniform random numbers on [0,1), and the next three are for normally-distributed numbers (mu=0, sigma=1).

For either type of random variate, the fastest method (of these three) is to generate all random numbers at once, store them in an array, and iterate over the array.  The problem is that I won't know how many of these numbers I'll need until after I run the program.

What I'd like to do is generate the random numbers in large batches.  Then when I use all the numbers in one batch, I'll just repopulate the object where they're stored.  The problem is that I don't know of a clean way to implement this.  One solution I came up with is the following:

```
N=1000000
numRepop=4
N1=N//numRepop
__rands__=[]
irand=-1

def repop():
    global __rands__
    __rands__=np.random.rand(N1)

repop()

def myRand():
    global irand
    try:
        irand += 1
        return __rands__[irand]
    except:
        irand=1
        repop()
        return __rands__[0]
```

but this is actually slower than any of the other options.

If I convert the numpy array to a list and then pop elements off, I get performance similar to just using numpy to generate random variates one at a time:

```
__r2__=[]

def repop2():
    global __r2__
    rr=np.random.rand(N1)
    __r2__=rr.tolist()

repop2()

def myRandb():
    try:
        return __r2__.pop()
    except:
        repop2()
        return __r2__.pop()
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**edit:** by "better" I just mean faster.  I'd also prefer deterministic (pseudo)random numbers

Comment: (1) Be careful with that kind of benchmarking ```Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls.``` (2) Why pop, if all you need is moving an index to select the position. No need to remove objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"? Do you have any other requirements than performance? For some purposes you need cryptographically safe random numbers, or you might need more than the default 32 bits of randomness.

Comment: @Håken Lid by "better" I just mean faster

Comment: @sascha (1) That's a good point that I wasn't aware of, but the timings I've done give fairly consistent results, so I'm not overly worried about it for now. (2) At first I tried indexing (with `repop` and `myRand`), but that was slower than `pop()` (with `repop2` and `myRandb`).

Comment: On *nix you can read `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` depending if you want more random or faster...

Comment: @dawg This does not add anything to this question. As OP made clear we are interested in non-cryptographic purposes only. Both your approaches are just super-slow, are not deterministic (a useful characteristic) and also may also provide worse quality random-numbers in general (for this task). Yeah, the last sentence is polarizing and you can ignore it if you want (i trust PRNGs more than entropy-estimation).

Comment: I suspect that the difference in benchmark is mostly caused by the fact that the test of looping over an array avoids an extra function call. So maybe it doesn't test how fast the numbers are generated.

Answer (score 2):

If it's faster to generate a lot of numbers at a time, you could make a generator that will cache batches. This works in python 3.5

```
def randoms(batchsize=10000):
    while True:
        yield from numpy.random.rand(batchsize)
```

Don't know if it's faster than your other implementations, but it's a never ending generator.

You can use it like any iterator:

```
prng = randoms()
for _ in range(1000000):
    foo(next(prng))
```

Or like this (but the loop will never exit):

```
for x in randoms():
    foo(x)
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to benchmark this myself, and I think that the difference is mostly because of the extra cost of function calls in python. I've tried to make the benchmarks more comparable by looping over a `range` in all cases, and the advantage of using a pregenerated array is smaller.

I get almost as good speed by using a micro optimalization trick where `numpy.random.rand` is assigned to a local variable, which speeds up the function call by quite a lot.

I also include the generator approach for comparison.

```
def randoms(batchsize):
    rand = numpy.random.rand
    while True:
        yield from rand(batchsize)
​
def test_generator(times):
    rand = randoms(1000).__next__
    for n in range(times):
        rand()

def test_rand(times):
    for n in range(times):
        numpy.random.rand() 

def test_rand_micro_opt(times):
    rand = numpy.random.rand
    for n in range(times):
        rand()

def test_array(times):
    array = numpy.random.rand(times)
    for n in range(times):
        array[n]
​
# ipython / jupyter magic %timeit command        
%timeit -n 1000 test_generator(10000)
%timeit -n 1000 test_rand(10000)
%timeit -n 1000 test_rand_micro_opt(10000)
%timeit -n 1000 test_array(10000)
​
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.09 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.93 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.74 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.57 ms per loop
```

Comment: I did some testing now and this took more than twice as long as simply using the `random` function of the `random` module. Test was `timeit(lambda: [next(prng) for _ in range(1000000)], number=10)` vs `timeit(lambda: [random() for _ in range(1000000)], number=10)`. Also tried storing `prng.__next__` in a variable and using that, but that didn't help much.

Comment: Yeah. It was based on the assumption was that making batches of numbers would save a lot of time, as OP's benchmarks seemed to show. But I think the difference in speed is mainly because of costly function calls that you don't get when looping directly over the array. With a generator there's no fewer function calls.

Comment: I benchmarked the generator version as well, but it's only slightly faster than the slowest test in my edited answer.

Comment: Would still be good to include that test in the answer, probably best with `rand = prng.__next__`.

Comment: You're right, that did make a difference. The simpler micro optimalization is still faster, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it significantly faster by not looking up the module and its function all the time.

```
def uRand_2(n):
    r = random.random
    for i in range(n):
        p(r())

def uRandnp1_2(n):
    r = np.random.rand
    for i in range(n):
        p(r())
```

Your versions timed on my PC:

```
[ 0.14439154  0.24865651  0.13786387  0.85637093  0.28924942  0.13338685]
```

My above two versions (corresponding to the first two of yours):

```
[ 0.10629296  0.15638423]
```

Oh and I don't see the point of calling `p`. I think that just adds noise and fogs the speed of the actual random number generation. Here are my times without calling `p`, i.e., just doing `r()`:

```
[ 0.04560113  0.1083169]
```

Comment: I wonder why the numpy function is so slow. There's also `numpy.random.random()` which seems to be about twice as fast as `numpy.random.rand()` when generating single values. The standard library version is still faster, though.

Comment: @HåkenLid Might be the parameters. I just tried `timeit('f()', 'def f(size=None): pass')` which is about twice as fast as `timeit('f()', 'def f(**args): pass')`.

Answer (score 0):

Not super beautiful, but that should work:

```
import numpy as np

class BatchedPRNG(object):
    def __init__(self, seed=0, batch_size=10000, dist='uniform'):
        self.prng = np.random.RandomState(seed)         # own random-stream !
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.dist = dist
        self.index = 0
        if self.dist == 'uniform':
            self.pool = self.prng.random_sample(size=self.batch_size)
        else:
            self.pool = self.prng.normal(size=self.batch_size)

    def sample_one(self):
        if self.index < self.batch_size:
            self.index += 1
            return self.pool[self.index-1]
        else:
            self.index = 1
            if self.dist == 'uniform':
                self.pool = self.prng.random_sample(size=self.batch_size)
            else:
                self.pool = self.prng.normal(size=self.batch_size)
            return self.pool[self.index-1]

dist = BatchedPRNG()
for i in range(11):
    print(dist.sample_one())
```

This follows the idea of encapsulation/object-oriented approaches at the cost of a function-call each time you want a new sample. It's also using an own PRNG-Stream, so that global calls to `np.random.X` in other parts of your code do not change the internalt state of this object.

Obviously you need to modify this if you want to use other distributions or need other features.

Sadly, you have to take care of benchmarking too.

**Edit: surprisingly slow**